# How find $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ${S_1} < {S_2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let ${S_1} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{4{n^2}} {\frac{1}{{{k^{\frac{1}{2}}}}}}$ and ${S_2} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^{\frac{1}{3}}}}}}$. How find all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ${S_1} < {S_2}$?

Comment: Have you tried computing a few terms?  Note that there are lots more terms on the left.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Ross Millikan's hint, each term in $S_1$ exceeds $\frac{1}{2n}$ and each term in $S_2$ is at most 1 so $S_1\geq 2S_2$

Comment: You make it far harder than it has to be. Each term in $S_1$ exceeds $1/(2n)$ and each term in $S_2$ is at most $1$

Comment: @RossMillikan updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  there are no such $n$.  Can you find something to compare each sum to, much simpler, that proves this?  It is not close, so you can make rather poor approximations.